# Why buttons inside movieclip isn't working (actionscript 2)

Tags: flash, button, actionscript-2, movieclip

I had a problem using buttons inside moviclip

This my scenario
I take a button in a frame inside movieclip,in next frame i take b button inside movieclip and its continues until z

When the a button clicked,then the frame going to next frame and move some movieclip in root,then b button clicked,then the frame going to next frame and also move some movieclip in root and its continues until y

The problem is when a button clicked (working) but the next button (b,c,d....) isn't working

this is my script

```js
stop();
nilai=0;//skor total
langkah=1;//gerakan pemain
angka=0;//dadu


jawabana.a1.onPress=function(){ //first button inside first frame of movieclip
 angka=0;
 angka=angka+1;
 nilai=nilai+1;
 langkah=langkah+1;
 _root.pemain._x = _root["kotak"+langkah]._x;
 _root.pemain._y = _root["kotak"+langkah]._y;
 _root.jawabana.gotoAndStop(langkah);
 _root.soal.gotoAndStop(langkah);
 trace(langkah);
}
jawabana.a2.onPress=function(){ //button on second frame of movieclip
 angka=0;
 angka=angka+1;
 nilai=nilai+1;
 langkah=langkah+1;
 _root.pemain._x = _root["kotak"+langkah]._x;
 _root.pemain._y = _root["kotak"+langkah]._y;
 _root.jawabana.gotoAndStop(langkah);
 _root.soal.gotoAndStop(langkah);
 trace(langkah);
}
```

a button is a1
b button is a2
c button is a3

Pleae help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wrote all the event listeners of all the buttons on the first frame.

If this guess is true, there will be a conflict that the actions will not be able to communicate to the buttons on the coming frames as those buttons are not loaded yet.

So you have to write each button event listener on its own frame.

Comment: i wrote all event on root frame

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm saying. Check the output panel you'll find that you are getting the following error:
`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

Comment: No, you have to write the listeners inside the MovieClip.

Comment: yes, i've do it but the result is NaN, how about if i give variable to langkah as integer, then i change thevariable to String